# Number theory: find $a, b$ such that $\frac{a}{b} = b.a$ in a general base $\mathcal{B}\neq 10$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was playing with numbers and thinking about this "coincidence"

$$\frac{5}{2} = 2.5$$

That is, for positive $a$ and $b$ we have

$$\frac{a}{b} = b.a$$

And those questions came into my mind:

**1.** Could we find all such integers pair $a, b$? (clearly in base $10$)

And due to the fact that we work in base $10$, a more general problem popped up, that is, to write our numbers in a base $\mathcal{B}\neq 10$  and thence look for triplets $(\mathcal{B}, a, b)$ such that

$$\frac{a}{b} = b.a$$

When $a, b$ are written in base $\mathcal{B}$.

**2.** Could we find a general formula that will produce infinitely many such integer triples?

I am not really into number theory, except for few little questions, so this is more a sort of "I am asking to you experts in the field" question.

If for some reason this problem is unclear or wrong or impossible, just tell me!

Thank you!

Comment: the title doesn't match the question

Comment: This question contains a generalisation to base $\mathcal B$, that question doesn't, so not really a duplicate (an argument could be made to close the other one as a duplicate of this).

Comment: @Galc127 Not a duplicate, this questions asks for a general base, not only decimal. Technically it's the other question which may be a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Not a duplicate, this questions asks for a general base, not only decimal. Technically it's the other question which may be a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 1):

In the base $10$ we have  $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{10b+a}{10}$$ which gives 
$$a=\frac{10b^2}{10-b}$$ and
$$\frac{10b^2}{10-b}\leq9$$ gives $$b\leq\frac{\sqrt{3681}-9}{20},$$
which gives $$b\le2.$$
Since $b=1$ is not valid, we obtain $b=2$ and $a=5$ only.

Comment: What about the possibility that $a$ is not a single digit number? Then, we would have $\frac{a}{b}=b+\frac{a}{10^n}$ where $n$ is the length of $a$...

Answer (score 1):

$$a=b\left(b+\dfrac a{10}\right)$$

$$\iff10a=b(10b+a)\iff a=\dfrac{10b^2}{10-b}=\dfrac{10(10-c)^2}c$$ setting $10-b=c$

$\implies 0<c<10$

$$a=10c-200+\dfrac{1000}c\implies c|1000$$

Comment: What about non decimal basis?

Comment: @ArtificialIntelligence, For base $r,$  $$a=b\left(b+\dfrac ar\right)$$

Comment: Since I am not familiar with number theory notation, what does $c|1000$ mean? Wonderful anyway!

Comment: @ArtificialIntelligence, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128004/is-the-notation-for-a-divides-b-standard

Comment: Another question: can we prove specifically that there are no triples when $13 \leq \mathcal{B} \leq 17$ ??

Comment: @ArtificialIntelligence, Why triples?

Comment: I meant there are no $a, b$ for these basis, sorry :D

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to do $\frac{a}{b}=b+\frac{a}{10}$ and this leads to $a=\frac{10b^2}{(10-b)}$. I think this may be a possible solution for case 1. Actually I do not have an idea for $\mathcal{B}\neq 10$.

Comment: For how much this answer is not a real answer, the user has not yet the reputation needed to post comments. I gave him a +1 for the answer/comment anyway, for he indeed tried to help.